# Attempting to force element to be on another line but not working

Tags: css

I'm wanting the p tag in this code to be on the next line but it's not working.

```
<label class="radioLabel qtyPrice" for={{"cost".$qties[$key]}} aria-label={{"cost".$qties[$key]}}>
  <span></span>
  {{ $qties[$key] . " / $" . $singleCost }}
  <p style="color: red; display: block;">{{ $qtyPerPiece[$key] . ' each' }} </p>
</label>
```

The css for these elements is:

```
.radioLabel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center; /* align vertical */
  position: relative;
  grid-template-columns: 20px auto 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in;
}

.radioLabel > span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #454861;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #bdbdbd);
}
```

I've also tried adding a line break like so:
{{ $qties[$key] . " / $" . $singleCost }} 
{{ $qtyPerPiece[$key] . ' each' }}

This is what I'm getting:
[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this the intended result you need to wrap them in a container with `flex-direction: column;`

[image]

```css
.radionLabelContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
    position: relative;
    grid-template-columns: 20px auto 100px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in;

}
.radioLabel {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.radioLabel > span {
    vertical-align:middle;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #454861;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #bdbdbd);
}
```

```
<div class="radionLabelContainer">
    <label class=" radioLabel qtyPrice" for={{"cost".$qties[$key]}} aria-label={{"cost".$qties[$key]}}>
        <span></span>
        {{ $qties[$key] . " / $" . $singleCost }}
    </label>
    <span style="color: red;">{{ $qtyPerPiece[$key] . ' each' }} </span>
</div>
```

For more details read this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/